# Permanently deleting a webpart on close

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In SharePoint when the user closes a web part, the web part is hidden but not deleted from the page. I want to delete the web part permanently from the page when the user clicks on close. Is there any way in which this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - but you can stop the close button appearing so the only alternative is to Delete.

- Toolpart > Advanced > Allow Close (uncheck)

Answer (score 0):

deletion of a webpart is not part of personalization feature.. if you delete the webpart it will be removed from that web part page permanantly and will not the part of this page any more.. however closing will close the webpart for particular user..